# Android ContentProvider grant access for one other application

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

My Android App provides a ContentProvider. Now I want a second app to get read and write access to this content provider, but all other apps should not get access.

I'm thinking of an access control by the package name. 
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Is that second application is signed by same certificate?

Comment: It's a different developer and they are using a different certificate but they will include my code to access my provider.